# Integration-Determinent

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$f(x)=\begin{vmatrix}
> \sec x&\cos x&\sec^2x+\cot x\csc x\\\cos^2x&\cos^2x&\csc^2x\\1&\cos^2x&\cos^2x\end{vmatrix}$$
>   Find $\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,dx.$

**My Thoughts**
1. Opening the determinent will use
very much time, not good for exam.
2. There should be a definite integral property that
may make it easy.

Please give me any **Hint**

**Edit** Thanks for answering .I made this post only for Hint.And I got it

Comment: I have tried to serach it through Approach0 but found nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expands into $\cos x-\sin^2x \cos^3x$, whose integral is quite simple to evaluate.
To see this, divide first row by $\sec x$. Then the row becomes: $1 \ \cos^2 x \ 1+\cot^2 x=\csc^2x$, Then change $R1->R1 - R3$, a transformation which doesn't change the determinant. Now, as first row has 2 zeros, it is easy to expand the determinant. The final determinant is simply $\sec x*$(new Determinant)